# ¿Cómo esperar a que se cierre un juego de steam?

Tags: c#

Estoy diseñando un Launcher que principalmente sirve de "puente" entre un juego antiguo y su emulador, aunque perfectamente se le puede poner un juego de pc y también lo lanza.

Mi problema llega al querer lanzar un juego de steam. Los abro desde el acceso directo `.url` que te deja steam en el escritorio y siempre me salta `InvalidOperationException` ya que el acceso directo no abre el juego directamente.

Por ello me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de capturar el proceso del juego y esperar a que finalice.

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
public void Launch()
{
    bool error = false;
    try
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + fileName+ "\"";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + arguments;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        process.Start();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException) { error = true; }

    if(!error)
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: cual de los quinientos procesos que lanza steam al abrir un juego queres??? :p

Comment: El propio del juego, que en el momento que se cierre el juego el programa vuelva a estar a pantalla completa

Comment: Yo empezaria a investigar por aqui: https://steamcommunity.com/dev?l=spanish

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de esta manera

```
public void Launch()
{
    bool error = false;
    try
    {
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + fileName+ "\"";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + arguments;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        process.Start();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException) { error = true; }

    if(!error)
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: por favor mira [answer] solo colocar código se considera de baja calidad; por favor dale editar y añade una explicación

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero desafortunadamente no ha funcionado. Para darte más información puedo decirte que si abro el juego con steam cerrado (ningún subproceso funcionando) el programa principal queda bloqueado y minimizado hasta que cierro steam.